# Why is 'insert into select' statement in SQL inserting as a new row and not inserting correctly?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-insert

I have table 1.

[image]

I have another empty table 2 with the following columns.

[image]

I want to insert into table 2 by selecting from table 1 - so I write the query as:

```
insert into table2(employee,id,zone,url) 
select employee, id, zone, concat('https://',employee,'.com/',id,'?',zone) 
from table1
```

Now my table 2 looks like this,

[image]

Now for the `authcode` column, I do the following and insert it into the table2.

```
insert into table2(authcode) 
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),HASHBYTES('MD5', substring(URL,8,100)),2) 
from table2.
```

But the insert happens differently like this AS AN ENTIRE NEW SET OF ROWS.

[image]

Can someone help me to insert the last column to the corresponding rows instead of it creating a new one?

Comment: Because that's what INSERT does -- it inserts new rows.  If you want to update existing rows, use UPDATE.

Answer (score 4):

What you should be doing is UPDATE the table to fill the column `authcode`, but you could do it all in 1 step while you are inserting the rows:

```
insert into table2(employee,id,zone,url, authcode) 
select 
  employee, 
  id, 
  zone, 
  concat('https://',employee,'.com/',id,'?',zone),
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),HASHBYTES('MD5', substring(concat('https://',employee,'.com/',id,'?',zone),8,100)),2) 
from table1
```

or if you want to update:

```
update table2
set authcode = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),HASHBYTES('MD5', substring(URL,8,100)),2) 
where authcode is null
```

Comment: Thanks forpas, beautifully explained.

Answer (score 2):

The result you are seeing is the intended behavior for an [INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) statement. It will always insert new rows.

If you want to modify existing rows your need to use an [UPDATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) statement.

You can either modify your INSERT to look like what @forpas has posted to get all this work done in one step. Another option is to modify the second INSERT to be an UPDATE like the following:

```
update table2
set authcode = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),HASHBYTES('MD5', substring(URL,8,100)),2)
```